Bottom bracket tightening old Mercier bike
(I don't know much about bike repair and I may have gotten some words wrong!)
I inherited this old Mercier. Everything else is good but the pedal spindle is quite loose. I want to tighten it but it looks I'll have to remove the crank arms. None of e.g. the Park Tool videos seem applicable for this design.

Which pieces should I remove?
Is there a way to tighten the spindle without removing the crank arms?





I believe if you remove the plastic caps you will find a bolt or a nut similar to the Park Tool Tutorials. You will need some standard home-owner tools such a small screwdriver to remove the plastic cap, 14mm socket and ratchet to remove the retaining bolt or nut. While this is the most common size it might also be an Allen head cap screw or something slightly larger or smaller. A pair of slip joint pliers and a large adjustable wrench will be needed to remove the bearing cup and the lock ring. The only special tool you will need is a Square tapered bottom bracket removal tool. Non professional models are under $10 US just check reviews as quality can vary. I would advise against just tightening it up. It is likely loose from bearing wear or lack of lubrication. The good thing is this type of Bottom Bracket is serviceable. It was designed to be disassembled, cleaned, regreased and adjusted with minimal effort. Also you may consider installing a modern sealed bearing unit but the switch will involve buying another tool to install the newer style.

Thanks for the great advice! I stupidly thought these golden caps were actual metal and couldn't be removed...
